# Why do I get a black box when I tile pictures with -filter_complex tile=2x1 in FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, image-processing

As I was trying to write a script (which attempts to join two pictures eventually) using FFmpeg I came across a very weird behaviour.

This is a command from I've found in the *[How to join two images into one with FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24604689/how-to-join-two-image-into-one-by-ffmpeg)* thread:

```
ffmpeg -i a.jpg -i b.jpg -filter_complex scale=120:-1,tile=2x1 output.jpg
```

- **Input:** *a.jpg*, *b.jpg*

  [image: a.jpg] [image: b.jpg]
- **Output:** *output.jpg*

  [image: output.jpg]

What happened to the B cat? Why is it missing from the output image? I couldn't find any information why `tile=2x1` behaves like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [tile](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tile) filter is when one wants to

> Tile several successive frames together.

To stack two frames horizontally, use

```
ffmpeg -i a.jpg -i b.jpg -filter_complex [1]scale=120:-1[b];[0][b]hstack output.jpg
```

Comment: I get this error "At least one output file must be specified"